# Permission denied when i run the git status command on Git bash

Tags: git-bash

I just recently started started using git bash because i heard it is a very useful thing to know if your trying to get into software development. I am following a tutorial on You tube to learn this and i came across and error when i run the "git status" command on Git Bash. I am relatively new to this software so i don't know how to approach or resolve the problem.

This is the error message i get when i run the command on Git Bash:

$ git status
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Music/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Videos/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
On branch main

No commits yet

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
.bash_history
.cisco/
.gitconfig
.idlerc/
.ssh/
AppData/
Contacts/
Downloads/
Favorites/
Links/
Music/
NTUSER.DAT
NTUSER.DAT{539d4566-25ef-11ee-98a1-d0395753b3fc}.TM.blf
NTUSER.DAT{539d4566-25ef-11ee-98a1-d0395753b3fc}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{539d4566-25ef-11ee-98a1-d0395753b3fc}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
OneDrive/
PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.2/
PycharmProjects/
Saved Games/
Searches/
Videos/
ntuser.dat.LOG1
ntuser.dat.LOG2
ntuser.ini
readme.txt
tim.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

I tried:

running the app as an administrator
closing the window and reopening
deleting the files i created through Git Bash and recreating them

[This is what i was expecting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3YGh.png)

Comment: The problem is not about git-bash. It is your system that does not allow you to read that directory. There are some dedicated/system/secure/etc directories in your computer that requires administrative privileges, which your regular login/account does not have that priviledge. In your system, there is a dedicated directory named as your username. Everything you do is stored in that directory. For example your desktop files, shortcuts are under that directory. it is kind of your workspace. Try to create a directory on your desktop and try again.

Comment: @Ahmet Emrebas How would i do that?

Comment: Stop playing with your system files. Work with a clean directory.

Comment: If you have tried to create a repository directly in your home folder, that is not a good idea. You want to create repository inside some empty directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

run GitBash 'Run as administrator'
or create a repository on Drive where you have full access